# React Inline Condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have issues setting an inline condition for my shipping price :

```
cart.shippingPrice =
  country === ("France" || "United States") ? toPrice(20) : toPrice(10);
```

Only when I select France the condition returns 20, but I want United States to return it as well, is there a typo ?

Comment: `("France" || "United States" )` evaluates first, and just becomes "France". You need to check `country === "France" || country === "United States`

Comment: thank you, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly check against each country:

```
country === "France" || country === "United States"
```

If you *"fear"* that more countries will come to the list, you could create an array:

```
const countries = ["France", "United States"]
```

and then do

```
countries.includes(country)
```

Comment: Ah nice suggestion of the `array`

Comment: this is very good, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In your expression and in question contents if it's returning `20` it means the condition is `true`.

Try:

```
cart.shippingPrice = (country === "France" || country === "United States) ? toPrice(20) : toPrice(10)
```